# Como evitar que node se detenga cuando cierro la consola

Tags: javascript, nodejs, console

tengo un entorno en node js que funciona perfecto al ejecutar node index.js pero cuando cierro la consola el entorno se detiene y no se sigue ejecutando, algún comando para hacer que node se siga ejecutando aún con la consola cerrada?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes instalar esta librería que lo hace de manera sencilla: [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever). Como su nombre lo indica, lo que hará es ejecutar un script de nodejs por siempre como un [daemon](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(inform%C3%A1tica)). El paquete tiene una serie de acciones y opciones con las cuales puedes manejar la ejecución de tu script.

Tienes que instalar la librería de manera global:

```bash
npm install forever -g
```

y puedes correr el script en el background con

```bash
forever start script.js
```

Comment: muchas gracias bro, problema resuelto.